# UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate dismiss animation with NSLayoutConstraint issue

Tags: ios, animation, autolayout

1) I have a task to present and dismiss modal UIViewController with custom animation.

2) Custom animation is to change alpha and move one child element

3) I created `FadeInAnimationController` and `FadeOutAnimationController` classes to implement  `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` like this:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    // obtain state from the context
    CIToViewController *toViewController = (CIToViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    // obtain the container view
    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];

    // set the intial state
    toViewController.view.alpha = 0.0f;
    toViewController.elementBottomPosition.constant -= 20.0f;
    [toViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];

    // add the view
    [containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];

    // animate
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext]
                     animations:^{
                         toViewController.view.alpha = 1.0f;
                         toViewController.elementBottomPosition.constant += 20.0f;
                         [toViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
                     }];
     }
```

4) `elementBottomPosition` is NSLayoutConstraint and it works fine for Present animation

5) **PROBLEM:**

For Dismiss animation `NSLayoutConstraint` doesn't work, so I had to do the same thing using Frame and it worked. It is not very good with AutoLayout and iOS7, but since I need to dismiss this view I don't care for its autolayout.

So the question is why NSLayoutConstraint approach doesn't work??? I logged constraints in `animateTransition`:

```
NSLog(@"constraints %@", fromViewController.view.constraints);
```

And they are still present.

Comment: `toViewController.elementBottomPosition.constant += 20.0f [toViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];` - is this part not working?

Comment: Yes, this part is not working, but only for Dismiss, Present works just fine

Comment: Can you explain in more detail in what way it's not working?

Comment: Does not react, on `elementBottomPosition.constant` change, simply disappears from the screen, without moving the subview element

Comment: Can you see if `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` on the disappearing controller are called before `animations:` block is executed?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Anyone found a solution to make the layout constraints work during custom dismiss animation?

Comment: Also getting the same problem.  I've confirmed that viewWillDisappear is called before the animateTransitions: block, but viewDidDisappear is not called until after it's all done.  The constraints are all still in the `constraints` collection on the superview.

Comment: Experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not set auto layout constants in your animation block.

```
toViewController.elementBottomPosition.constant -= 20.0f;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
toViewController.elementBottomPosition.constant += 20.0f;

//Animation block here ^{
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```